# Trim filename with RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex

Yo!

After way to complicated solutions (jQuery or over 20 lines of pure JavaScript) when I searched on Google and Stack Overflow how to style an file upload button, I came with something quite simple inspired by [this site](https://coderwall.com/p/uer3ow). Instead of trying to style the input field (which only works very limited with some webkit stuff or JS hacks), make it invisible, use a label to select a file and make it look like a button.

```html
<form enctype='multipart/form-data' action='upload.php' method='post'>
    <label onchange="document.getElementById('fakefile').innerHTML = document.getElementById('realfile').value.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '');">
        <span id='fakefile'>select file</span>
        <input id='realfile' name='uploaded' type='file' style='display:none' />
    </label>
    <input type='submit' value='upload' />
</form>
```

```css
#fakefile, input {
    background-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.8);
    border: 1px solid rgba(100, 100, 100, 0.5);
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: #efe;
    font: 11px 'Ubuntu';
    margin: 2px 1px;
    outline: none;
    padding: 4px 5px;
    text-align: center;
    width: auto;
}
```

Demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MRN6S/)

My problem now is this part: `document.getElementById('fakefile').innerHTML = document.getElementById('realfile').value.replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, '')`

The file is read from the real upload field and copied to the fake button, but I also wanted to limit the number of characters.

On [regex101](http://regex101.com/#javascript) I tested `.*[\\\/]([a-z0-9.]{0,10})/i` with the string `C:\fakepath\veryveryverylongfilname.jpg`.
The site says "veryveryve", which looks okay. But when I use this in my script, nothing happens. Not even the path is cut off anymore.

After reading [javascriptkit](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/redev3.shtml), it looks like I have to use `.match` instead of `.replace`, but it didn't work either. Since I barely know JavaScript and used RegEx only a few times at university, I don't really get where I made the mistake.

My goal is following:

- cut off path
- if strlen <= 16 return complete filename
- if strlen > 16 replace filename to (first 7 characters)(...)(last 7 characters)

Example:

`C:\fakepath\veryveryverylongfilname.jpg` becomes `veryver...ame.jpg`
`C:\fakepath\shortname.jpg` becomes `shortname.jpg`

Maybe it's possible to nest the replace function like `value.replace(replace(/^.*[\\\/]/, ''), do some magic here to trim long filename)`?

If that's too difficult it would also be enough for me to return (first 14 characters)(...) for strlen > 16.

Is this possible with only one RegEx or do I need some extra variables and functions?

Comment: The value isn't set yet when you're trying to get it, and that's not the way to get the filename, the filename is available in the files array, search around this site for how to get the filename.

Comment: Of course it is, try the fiddle link (tested in Safari, Chrome and Firefox). I can cut off the path and the filename is visible as label. I just don't know the RegEx to trim the filename. This is just about how to modify the displayed filename in the label, not how to process the uploaded file in PHP later.

Comment: Seems it actually is, it's still not the right way to do that.

Comment: This is **http://jsfiddle.net/MRN6S/1/**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using only one regex could be tricky and prabably not very clear. And keep in mind that regexes are already a mess to write and maintain *per se*.

So keep things separate and try this:

```
var file = document.getElementById('realfile').value,
    match, output;

if (match = file.match(/\\([^\\]{7})[^\\]+?([^\\]{7})$/))
    output = match[1] + "..." + match[2];
else if (match = file.match(/[^\\]+$/))
    output = match[0];
else output = file;

document.getElementById('fakefile').innerHTML = output;
```

**Edit**: according [to the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20121025/common-input-element-apis.html#dom-input-value), the `value` property of a `<input type="file">` element is either an empty string (if no file has been selected) or a string beginning with `"c:\fakepath\"` (even on OSX or Linux), followed by the file name of the selected file (or the first selected file, if `multiple` is true).

So, we can bake another, shorter, version:

```
document.getElementById('fakefile').innerHTML =
        document.getElementById('realfile').value.substring(12)
            .replace(/([^\\]{7})[^\\]+?([^\\]{7})$/, "$1...$2");
```

Comment: Only tested on OS X so far, but it seems like Linux is using c:\fakepath\file.ext too, so [\/] can be dropped. Also shortened the code a bit (http://jsfiddle.net/6mn8e/), but for understanding your long version is better. Thank you :)

Comment: @neco You're welcome. I didn't know that the fake path was Windows-like on other platforms too - but I checked and it's actually [in the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20121025/common-input-element-apis.html#dom-input-value). Good to know. I changed the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I added some options [to your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/optyler/MRN6S/3/)... :-p

You can configure the "etcetera" part, all the code is dynamic.

```
var etc = '[...]'; // this will be the etcetera text abcd[...]jkl.doc
```

You can configure the length of the "trimed" text

```
<label onchange="doTheMagic(20)">
```